# Use a calculated field as a parameter?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

In Microsoft Report Builder I'd like to set a calculated field as a dropdown list parameter. Is this possible?

I have a simple calculated field for determining whether a case is open or closed `[=IIf(Fields!Case_Closed.Value Is Nothing, "Open", "Closed")]` which works fine. I have also been able to add this as a parameter to the report, however I am having difficulty finding a way to make this a multiple-option dropdown list.

For standard fields I would use the filter option within the data set query and ask for the values in a field to be in a list, and then allow multiple values to be selected within the parameter option. As I can't access the calculated field this way, is there another route available for making the two calculated field values available as a dropdown, being able to select either or both options?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dataset that holds you drop down field
For example

```
select  'Open' AS Case_Closed 
UNION
select  'Closed' AS Case_Closed
```

and use the value of the dataset in your Parameter
Connect the parameter to the Main dataset. Remember to configure your oarameter setting to drop down List

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this same by adding the Values in the **Available Values** Option in SSRS

And in **General** Option Select "Allow multiple Values" check box as **TRUE**.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thank you. I'm still struggling to get this set up though, what exactly would I need to put in here please? I have tried using the same kind of expression under Value that I have used for the calculated field but it won't let me use a field in the expression?